# How to debug an execution line

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I want do debug this line:

```
exec("mysqldump --add-drop-table -h 127.0.0.1 -u$db_user -p$db_pass $db_name > $db_name.sql");
```

... because this is not working. Is it possible?
I want to create a script that get all content from several databases and this line is not working, it creates a .sql file but does not save any info. there.

Comment: Have you tried running it from the command-line/shell/terminal directly instead of from `php`?  You will get more debugging output that way.

Comment: You can debug it by running it on your own to see what happens

Comment: First, put whole command into variable and print it out.Then execute same command from shell under same user php runs.This will 100% reveals problems

Comment: ok ill try it on the command-line

Comment: Also, a security note: putting the password directly into your shell command is a really bad idea - any user with shell access to the same machine can see your password in plain while the command runs, just issuing a `w` command is all it takes (try it out yourself if you want).

Comment: i tried to use putty, but i cant configure that to localhost

Comment: If you are on a linux server, does the php/apache have permissions to execute the mysqldump command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a space after the `-u`. [reference link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_user)

```
exec("mysqldump --add-drop-table -h 127.0.0.1 -u $db_user -p$db_pass $db_name > $db_name.sql");
```

Comment: `echo` out the line before execution then run it directly in the command line.  if there are still issues verify your script has access to run `mysqldump` and the username has rights to the database